# How can I transform a tuple subclass made by namedtuple to tuple itself?

Tags: python, tuples, namedtuple

I'm using python while some method requires tuple as its argument. Although instance created by namedtuple is tuple subclass, but it seems that I still need to transform it to tuple.
Is there any way to transform the tuple subclass made by namedtuple to tuple quickly? Thanks!

Comment: Oh no! I think I smell `type()`. Should be using `isinstance()`, or even better, just use duck typing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `namedtuple` instance `x` can be converted to a tuple using `tuple(x)`, but you shouldn't need to do so.  If some code only accepts tuples, but no `namedtuple`s, I consider that code broken.  (There *may* be special cases that require such a behaviour, but I can't think of any right now.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I understood the problem right, you can just instantiate tuple using your namedtuple as an argument:

```
>>> T = namedtuple('T', 'x y')
>>> isinstance(tuple(T(1, 2)), tuple)
True
>>> 
>>> tuple(T(1,2))
(1, 2)
```